# navigation submenu items are not appearing in an iframe

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

I have 3 iframes set up.  iframe 1 is for the heading of the page; iframe 2 is for the navigation menu and submenu; iframe 3 is for the content.  I have been unable to have the submenu items in a navigation bar (resides in an iframe 2) show up.  I have the following code for any feedback on how I can over come this issue.

```
index.php
    <DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   
<style>

#headingiframe {
position: static;
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-Y:hidden;
z-index: 1;
}
#contentiframe {
position : relative;
left:0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

#menuiframe {
position: relative;
overflow-Y:visible;
z-index: 5;
}

</style>

<div id="headingiframe">
 <iframe width="100%" height="12%" src="header_on_screen.php" scrolling=NO >         </iframe>   
</div>

<div id="menuiframe">
<iframe width="100%" height="10%" src="show_menu.php" scrolling=NO >     </iframe>
</div>

<div id="contentiframe">
<iframe width="100%" height="70%" src="contents.php" scrolling=YES > </iframe>
</div>
        </head>  
        </body>
    </html>

show_menu.php

    <DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   

<style>
#outer {
position: relative;
left:0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; 
z-index: 3;
    overflow-Y:visible;
}

#inner{
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
        overflow-Y:visible;
}

.cover {
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow-Y: visible;
    height:100%;
 }


ul#menu, ul#menu ul.sub-menu {
padding:4;
margin: 4;
z-index: 6;
overflow-Y: visible;
display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu li, ul#menu ul.sub-menu li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
overflow-Y: visible;
    z-index: 6;
}
/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu li a, ul#menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
background: #666;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
overflow-Y: visible;
    z-index: 6;
}
/*Make the parent of sub-menu relative*/
ul#menu li {
position: relative;
overflow-Y: visible;
    z-index: 6;
}
/*sub menu*/
ul#menu li ul.sub-menu {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0;
width: 100px;
z-index: 6;
overflow-Y: visible;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul.sub-menu {
display:block;
position:absolute;
overflow-Y: visible;
z-index:6;
}

</style>
<head>
<body>

<div id="outer">

<div id="inner">
    <div id="navMenu">    
        <ul id="menu">

            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <iframe class="cover" src="about:blank" ></iframe>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                     <iframe class="cover" src="about:blank" ></iframe>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Menu 5</a>
            </li>



       </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

        </head>  
        </body>
 </html>        



Header_on_screen.php

<?php // header_on_screen.php

echo <<<_END

<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<table style="width:100%">
    <TR>
        <TH style="color:green;text-align:center"><h2>iFrame Management System </h2></TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TH scope="colgroup">Version 0.6 </TH>
    </TR>
</table>
_END;

?>      



 Contents.php
 <?PHP  


    echo"<BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.
        <BR> The contents iFrame is where all contents will appear.

"

?>
```

Comment: do you get a network error related to loading the second `iframe`'s contents?

Comment: I did not get an error.  The behavior is that the submenu item are not all showing up in front of the contents iframe.

Comment: content iframe is overlapping the submenu?

Comment: That is correct - the content iframe is overlapping the submenu from the menu iframe.

Comment: try dropping `top:0;` from your style declarations on `#contentiframe`.

Comment: I removed the top: 0  from the style but it still does not show the submenu items (menu 2 and menu 4). Using Chrome on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Using frames or iframes for somehow creating webpage layouts are very very bad choices. Because they are actually different pages embeded in one page. Even search engines count as different pages. In 2018 you simply should not use iframes in that way.

Comment: I appreciate your input but I have seen some web sites with the menu bar fixed (no scrollable) while the contents is scrollable.  Having the menu bar with submenus  makes navigation much easier than to have to go back to the top of the window to select another menu/submenu.

Comment: you can actually create sticky menu bars using some simple css codes. In frameworks like Bootstrap this has been figured out. The idea of this is to make the navigation bar fixed position by {position:fixed} and give an exact position to the navigation bar. you can check out this example in bootstrap 4
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbar-fixed/

Comment: Peshraw.  Thanks for the suggestion. I looked it over and it is hard fo me to grasp it all.   I am developing this web app as an exercise to get my arms  around PHP, HTML, Javascript and MySQL.    The web app is about 30% complete.  The nagging issue is that the I am trying to out the menus  and associated submenus in an iframe but the submenus are not fully visible outside of the iframe. I was not planning to get immersed into jquery and bootstrap at this point.  Do you have any thoughts on what is missing in the style sections that will fix this issue?